# Cannot see UI elements in listbox

Tags: xaml, layout, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, listbox-control

I have a page that has a ListBox. Whose items are not getting visible.But my ListBox is visible , I have checked it by changing its Background Color. Here is my ListBox :-

```
<Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
            <ListBox Name="friend_list"  Margin="0,10,0,0">
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel>
                            <Grid Width="{Binding ElementName=friend_list,Path=ActualWidth}">
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <StackPanel Grid.Column="1"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,30,80,10">
                                    <TextBlock  TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Diana Jayson" Name="username" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="40" Margin="12,0,0,0" Foreground="#FF4D6082" Width="250" />
                                    <TextBlock Text="Diana Jayson" Name="location" FontSize="40" Margin="20,0,0,0" Foreground="#FF4D6082"/>
                                    <TextBlock Text="Diana Jayson" Name="sate" FontSize="40" Margin="20,0,0,0" Foreground="#FF4D6082"/>
                                </StackPanel>

                                <Image  Grid.Column="0" Source="Assets\profile-placeholder.gif" Width="160" Height="160" Stretch="Fill" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,0,0,0">
                                    <Image.Clip>
                                        <EllipseGeometry  Center="80,80" RadiusX="80" RadiusY="80" />
                                    </Image.Clip>
                                </Image>
                            </Grid>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>
        </Grid>
```

Comment: have you binded any list to the listbox as it appears from your code that you have not . ?

Comment: no i did not i am just testing UI

Comment: you need to populate the `ListBox` by setting it's `ItemsSource` property. The `DataTemplate` is used to generate UI for each item in the `ItemsSource`

Comment: SO i can not use UI elements that have default values?

Comment: no you cant you can check where to add source in my answer below and you will have to make a list of some class object which contains all the property of the things you want to display on listbox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you will have to bind the list of element to the listbox to display its member ..

like this....

```
<Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
            <ListBox Name="friend_list"  ItemSource="{Binding yourlistname}" Margin="0,10,0,0">
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel>
                            <Grid Width="{Binding ElementName=friend_list,Path=ActualWidth}">
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <StackPanel Grid.Column="1"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,30,80,10">
                                    <TextBlock  TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Diana Jayson" Name="username" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="40" Margin="12,0,0,0" Foreground="#FF4D6082" Width="250" />
                                    <TextBlock Text="Diana Jayson" Name="location" FontSize="40" Margin="20,0,0,0" Foreground="#FF4D6082"/>
                                    <TextBlock Text="Diana Jayson" Name="sate" FontSize="40" Margin="20,0,0,0" Foreground="#FF4D6082"/>
                                </StackPanel>

                                <Image  Grid.Column="0" Source="Assets\profile-placeholder.gif" Width="160" Height="160" Stretch="Fill" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,0,0,0">
                                    <Image.Clip>
                                        <EllipseGeometry  Center="80,80" RadiusX="80" RadiusY="80" />
                                    </Image.Clip>
                                </Image>
                            </Grid>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>
        </Grid>
```

and in the template you can directly bind the ui with the properties which are inside your list object..

I hope this might help...